# MongoDB 6 version error when used replaceRoot in aggregate

Tags: php, mongodb

I am update my mongoDB version 3.6 to 6.0.5 after update version my application not working some filter functionality. Every time getting error:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: 'newRoot' expression  must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: ",{"_id":{"$oid":"644b54928b59d02b7225ee1b"},"hotelCode":"0001","hotelId":[{"test":"0001"}],"name":"ROSE DUBAI","address1":"metro station","location":"","latitude":25.25424,"longitude":55.30114,"phone":"971-4-3558355","thumbNailUrl":"/images/?im in /vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php:219**
```

Please find below my code. I used this mongoDB script with PHP version 7.2.

```
$map_js_string = "function () {
                var selected_room_types = {$selected_room_types};
                var selected_meal_bases = {$selected_meal_bases};
                var selected_supplier   = {$selected_supplier};
                var selected_refund_value = {$selected_refund_value};
                var matching_room_count = 0;
                var moreDelete = true;
                while (moreDelete) {
                    moreDelete = false;
                    var suppliers = Object.keys(this.HotelProperty);
                    for (var supplier_index = 0; !moreDelete && supplier_index < suppliers.length; supplier_index++) {
                        if (this.HotelProperty.hasOwnProperty(suppliers[supplier_index])) {
                            for (var index = 0; !moreDelete && index < this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]].length; index++) {
                                for (var room_index = 0; !moreDelete && undefined !== this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index] && undefined !== this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.room_rates && room_index < this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.room_rates.length; room_index++) {
                                    var room_category = this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.room_rates[room_index].room_category;
                                    var meal_basis = this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.room_rates[room_index].meal_basis;
                                    if(undefined !== this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.refund_policy) {
                                        var refund_policy = this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.refund_policy;
                                    } else {
                                        var refund_policy = '';
                                    }
                                    var source_type = this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.supplier_data.sourceType;
                                    if (typeof meal_basis == 'string' && typeof room_category == 'string' && typeof source_type == 'string') {
                                        meal_basis = meal_basis.replace(/&/, 'and');
                                        meal_basis = meal_basis.replace(/\\|/, '');
                                        meal_basis = meal_basis.replace(/<br>/i, '');
                                        meal_basis = meal_basis.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g, '');
                                        if ((selected_meal_bases.length == 0 || selected_meal_bases.indexOf(meal_basis.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (selected_room_types.length == 0 || selected_room_types.indexOf(room_category.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (selected_supplier.length == 0 || selected_supplier.indexOf(source_type.toLowerCase()) != -1) && (selected_refund_value.length == 0 || selected_refund_value.indexOf(refund_policy.toLowerCase()) != -1)) {
                                            matching_room_count++;
                                        } else {
                                            // delete the room
                                            this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.room_rates.splice(room_index, 1);
                                            if (this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]][index].RateInfo.room_rates.length == 0) {
                                                this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]].splice(index, 1);
                                                if (this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]].length == 0) {
                                                    if (Array.isArray(this.HotelProperty)) {
                                                        this.HotelProperty.splice(suppliers[supplier_index], 1);
                                                    } else {
                                                        delete this.HotelProperty[suppliers[supplier_index]];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            // break loop and start over
                                            moreDelete = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (matching_room_count > 0) {
                    emit(this._id, this);
                }
            }";
            
          
            $map_js_function = new MongoDB\BSON\Javascript($map_js_string);

            $reduce_js_string = "function(key, val_arr) {
                var joined = '';
                for(var i in val_arr) {
                    joined = joined + ',' + JSON.stringify(val_arr[i]);
                }
                return joined;
            }";
            $reduce_js_function = new MongoDB\BSON\Javascript($reduce_js_string);
             
            $mr_status = $dbnew->command(array(
                "mapreduce" => $temp_paging_collection,
                "map" => $map_js_function,
                "reduce" => $reduce_js_function,
                "out" => $mapreduce_result,
            ));
            unset($mr_status);

            $array_agree = array(
                array('$replaceRoot' => array('newRoot' => '$value')),
                array('$sort' => $sorting),
                array('$out' => $paging_collection),
            );

            $out = $dbnew->$mapreduce_result->aggregate($array_agree, $options);
```

How can short this issue. any one have any idea ? about this error.

Comment: `mapreduce` is deprecated at should be replaced by other functions, see [Map-Reduce to Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/map-reduce-to-aggregation-pipeline/). Instead of a loop `for(var i in val_arr) { joined = joined + ',' + ...` try `joined = val_arr.join(",")`

Comment: Sorry, Not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Did you convert `mapreduce` to other functions? And why do you create JavaScript inside PHP? Either do all in PHP or use JavaScript (i.e. Node.js) for all. The code does not look so complicate to migrate it into a single language. Note, you can also use `toPHP(fromJSON(...))` or `toRelaxedExtendedJSON(fromPHP(....))` to compose the aggregation pipeline.